# Can I fill web forms with Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, form-submit

Now I'm using iMacros to extract data from a web and fill forms submitting the data.

But iMacros is a expensive tool.  I need a free library and I've read about Scrapy for data minning.  I's a litle more complex to programming with it but the money rules.

The question is if I can fill html forms with Scrapy and submit to the web page.  I don't want to use Javascript, I want to use exclusively Python scripts.

I searched in http://doc.scrapy.org/ but I didn't found nothing about form-submit.

Comment: It's a web-scraper, not a web-request library. Actually got this link from another question here on SO just 5min ago.. try: http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a view on it.  The web form uses the POST method, and I need to upload files too.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Still can't do it with scrapy :P Every other library that's not used for scraping can tho :)

Comment: iMacros is not expensive at all. The FireFox addon is good enough for most of the people. You just have to do some JavaScript scripting.

Comment: @macroscripts iMacros is cool, the scripting interface (API) is very powerfull and easy to use, but it costs $995 for the enterprise edition (the only one that supports scripting interface, and I really need it).  I purchased the license the last year, but in a few months I'll expires and I'm look for an alternative solution.

Comment: You got it wrong. You can use scripting with iMacros addon to. Just write script in JavaScript and execute it via iMacros addon. Here is a YT example. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36ZEgrKJxeU

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `scrapy.http.FormRequest` class.

The FormRequest class extends the base Request with functionality for dealing with HTML forms

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#formrequest-objects

Answer (score 0):

[Mechanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/) is a python library that lets you automate interactions with a website. It supports HTML form filling.

Comment: I need Python 3 support.  I'm attempting with [Requests](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Just use scrapy as surfer190 suggested. or... try Selenium (headless with the HTMLUNIT driver)

Answer (score 0):

The below program explains you how to fill a form:

```
import mechanize
import cookielib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import html2text
# Browser
br = mechanize.Brenter code hereowser()

# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

# Follows refresh 0 but not hangs on refresh > 0
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

# User-Agent (this is cheating, ok?)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

# The site we will navigate into, handling it's session
br.open('http://gmail.com')

# Select the first (index zero) form
br.select_form(nr=0)

# User credentials
br.form['Email'] = 'user'
br.form['Passwd'] = 'password'
# Login
br.submit()

# Filter all links to mail messages in the inbox
all_msg_links = [l for l in br.links(url_regex='\?v=c&th=')]
# Select the first 3 messages
for msg_link in all_msg_links[0:3]:
    print msg_link
    # Open each message
    br.follow_link(msg_link)
    html = br.response().read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    # Filter html to only show the message content
    msg = str(soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'msg'})[0])
    # Show raw message content
    print msg
    # Convert html to text, easier to read but can fail if you have intl
    # chars
#   print html2text.html2text(msg)
    print
    # Go back to the Inbox
    br.follow_link(text='Inbox')

# Logout
br.follow_link(text='Sign out')
```

Comment: I guess it's not about Scrapy.