# How to scrape same data from thousands of authenticated urls?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I need to scrape data from more than 50 thousand different urls(`....com0\?cid=1&aid=23&...`), only "cid"and "aid" is changing. Always need same data fields, with same selectors. What approach do you suggest? Webpage has SSO authentication as a browser prompt

[image: picture below]

I am thinking to use scrapy library, but with no previous experience with scraping, it could be unreachable goal. I am able to do that with selenium and webdriver, but it is taking too long

Comment: Given the website features you mention, Scrapy may not be a good approach if you have no experience with it and you have a close dead line. Scrapy is great to handle complex websites with great performance, but it requires you to learn a bit first (HTML vs DOM, asynchronous programming, [dynamic content handling](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html)…)

Comment: Does the website require JavaScript to operate? If not, cURL might be fine.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with scrapy easily and faster than selenium.

You can simply set your urls with a loop

```
urls = ('http://www.example.com/page/{}'.format(i) for i in range(1,49999))
```

You can then use the [formrequest code shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21929473/can-i-fill-web-forms-with-scrapy) to fill the form.